# Sandbox MasterPass: C# Merchant Server SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, mastercard

I've integrated Masterpass in our C# asp.net project by using merchant server SDK and lightbox implementation. It has worked fine until yesterday in sandbox envinronment when I started to always get a SdkErrorResponseException: Completed: BadRequest

It happens when I call sdk methods like RetrievePaymentData and/or CreateAccessToken.

I've installed the following nuget packages:

Com.MasterCard.Masterpass.Merchant v1.0.0

Com.MasterCard.Sdk.Core v1.1.4

Have you ever got a similar problem?

Thank you very much.